# How can drone bees be born from unfertilized eggs?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, bees, gamete, zygosity

I am learning about Drone bees and I keep reading that they are born from unfertilized eggs.

Now here is my question: if eggs are gametes and therefore reproductive cells, how can they turn into a new living being without being fertilized? If that is possible, then it would mean that the gamete is already a living being/bee from the moment of its creation.

What am I missing? Is there some "activation" process that substitute the fertilization in the case of bees?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137230/discussion-on-question-by-federico-gentile-how-can-drone-bees-be-born-from-unfer).